# Cannot write in a file when using starting a program using the console

Tags: python, file, console

I've started Python recently, and I want to create a program which read a calculation in a file, execute it (using the `eval()` function) and write the result in another file. This program must be started with the console.

I've created the program, which works perfectly when I start it by double clicking it. But when I start the program with the console, it doesn't write the result in the file, and I don't get any errors. I know the calculation has been done, because the result is written in the console.

I've tried by running the program with `.py` extension, and compiling it to an executable, using `pyinstaller`. They work with a double-click, but not from the console.

Here are the commands I used to run the programs :

```
F:\Path\To\App\calculator.exe

C:\Path\To\Python\python.exe F:\Path\To\App\calculator.py
```

The code I use to read, evaluate and write the calculation

```py
input = open('calcul.txt', 'r')
output = open('result.txt', 'w')

calcul = input.read()
print(calcul)
print(eval(calcul).toString())
output.write(eval(calcul).toFileString())

input.close()
output.close()

def toString(self):
        number = str (round(self.m_number, 4))
        number_scientific = str(format(self.m_number, ".3E"))
        imprecision = str (round(self.m_imprecision, 4))
        imprecision_scientific = str(format(self.m_imprecision, ".3E"))
        relative_imprecision = str(round(self.m_relative_imprecision * 100, 2))

        return "\t  Number \t\t= " + number + " \t= " + number_scientific + "\n\t  Imprecision \t\t= " + imprecision + " \t= " + imprecision_scientific + "\n\t  Relative Imprecision \t= " + relative_imprecision + "%\n\t"

def toFileString(self):
        return str (round(self.m_number, 4)) + '\n' + str (round(self.m_imprecision, 4))
```

When I run the console as administrator, I have that:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>F:\Users\Ludovic\Desktop\Apprentissage\C++\Qt\calculator\python_calculator\calculator.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculator.py", line 376, in <module>
    calcul = input.read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calcul.txt'
[26580] Failed to execute script calculator

C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:\Users\Ludovic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe F:\Users\Ludovic\Desktop\Apprentissage\C++\Qt\calculator\python_calculator\calculator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Users\Ludovic\Desktop\Apprentissage\C++\Qt\calculator\python_calculator\calculator.py", line 373, in <module>
    input = open('calcul.txt', 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'calcul.txt'
```

Comment: Are you using windows cmd as console? If so, try to run it as administrator.

Comment: I open it with windows+r then cmd

Comment: got [shield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z73HF.png) icon there?

Comment: I've added what I get when I use the console as administrator in the post

Comment: Change `input = open('C:\your_path_to_file\calcul.txt', 'r')` and `output = open('C:\your_path_to_file\result.txt', 'w')`

Comment: It works only for the .py program, but I don't want to use absolute pathes because I want to share that program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run console as administrator

Add path tou your `input` and `output` files

```
input = open('your_path_to_file\\calcul.txt', 'r') 
output = open('your_path_to_file\\result.txt', 'w')
```

Or put files in script folder and then call them like this

```
import sys

input = open(sys.path[0]+'\\calcul.txt', 'r')
output = open(sys.path[0]+'\\result.txt', 'w')
```

#### Update

for unversal file path for .exe and .py try this (files should be in .exe and .py folder)

```
import sys

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = ''
else:
    application_path = sys.argv[0]+'\\'

input = open(application_path+'calcul.txt', 'r')
output = open(application_path+'result.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: It doesn't work for the .exe (I get the error : ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\calcul.txt'```) but the other one do, but as I said before, I don't want to use absolute pathes.

Comment: Well, you can compile to .exe one version of script, and leave another version for cmd exec.

Comment: In fact I didn't try the second solution, because I don't understand it. Could you quickly explain me how to do that, please ?

Comment: Reading the docs is always right decision :) Watch my update after.

Comment: It works perfecty, I just add to remove the program name at the end of ```application_path```.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not in the directory you wished write your txt file for exemple:
if you are here in the cmd: `MyFolder\`
and you execute your python file by writting: `python MyFolder\Python_prog\program.py`
the .txt file will be written in `MyFolder\` not in `MyFolder\Python_prog\`
I'm not sure because I've never tried out with python but I had the same kind of Errors with JavaScript

Comment: I've checked but there's nothing

Comment: Thanks to give me an awnser. I don't know why that doesn't work